# d3 selections broken in Chrome 30

Tags: google-chrome, d3.js

CSS selectors like ".chart >path", or ".chart text" are broken in the latest version of Chrome (30). ".chart" or "path" still work. Sizzle doesn't help for this. Does a workaround exist?

Comment: When I say "CSS selectors" I mean their usage in d3js:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7cS2T/ works fine in my Chrome 30.0.1599.69. Not in yours?

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 30.0.1599.114, Ubuntu 13.10